# Терадата: Добавление нового столбца в волатильную таблицу

Tags: teradata

Доброй ночи. Я была бы очень благодарна вам за помощь. Я не могу найти решение для добавления нового столбца в существующую таблицу. Есть данные (таблиа *DSRV_SRVP_new*): **ID, NUM, SRV, SRV_txt, Date**. Я хоу к каждому значению **ID, NUM** добавить новую запись: SRV = '' (в формате decimal(18,3)), SRV_txt = 'Total' (в формате varchar(150)) и Date = 01.01.1900 (в формате dd.mm.yyyy)
Пробовала такой код:

```
    CREATE MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE DSRV_SRVP_new1 AS (
        SELECT  distinct a.ID, a.NUM,
                         To_Date('01.01.1900', 'dd.mm.yyyy') as Date,
                 TO_NUMBER('') as SRV,
                 'Total' as SRV_txt
        FROM DSRV_SRVP_new a
        ) 
WITH DATA NO PRIMARY INDEX  ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```

Я получила новые столбцы с необходимыми значениями, но формат новых столбцов не тот, который нужен. Я попыталась изменить формат с помощью функции ALTER, но это выдает ошибку

> Syntax error, expected something like a name or a Unicode delimited identifier or a 'SET' keyword or a 'CONVERT_TABLE_HEADER' keyword between the word 'DSRV_SRVP_new1' and the 'ALTER' keyword

Я попыталась использовать "format", но это также выдает ошибку. Вероятно, есть какое-то простое решение, и оно "на поверхности", но я не могу его найти :(